# Git 不要になったローカルリポジトリの削除方法は？

Tags: git

Git 初心者でございます。

ローカルリポジトリの作成は... `git init` で作成しました。

さて、プロジェクトが終了し、不要になったローカルリポジトリは、どのように削除するのでしょうか？

Comment: `rm -rf local_repos/` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ git status
```

で、コミット漏れがないか、名残惜しいものがないか確認して

```
$ git fetch
$ git log -1
$ git log -1 origin
```

で二つのログを比較してプッシュ漏れがないか(相違がないか)確認して

```
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf {レポジトリ名}
```

で、ディレクトリを消去。

( git を使ったことによる特別な要素はトップにある `.git` ディレクトリだけです。)

Answer (score 3):

```
git branch --delete $(git branch --merged master | grep -v '^*\\|  master$')
```

これでマスタに取り込まれたブランチが削除されます。
残ったブランチがマスタに取り込まれていないブランチです。それぞれリモートにpushされていないか確認すると良いです。OSS なら漏れなく push してしまうのに `git push --all` で良いかと思います。

その後はディレクトリごと消してしまっていいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

プロジェクト自体がGithubなどのサーバー上のリポジトリに存在してローカルのリポジトリが必要なくなったのであればプロジェクトのディレクトリそのものを削除してしまえばOKです。

プロジェクト自体は残すけども、Gitでの管理をしなくなったのであればプロジェクトのディレクトリに`.git`という隠しディレクトリができていますのでそのディレクトリを削除すれば`git init`で生成されたファイルは全て削除されます。